# Visual Studio crashes on start up

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, startup

I've been using Visual Studio 2010 for over a year now to work on XNA games for the Windows Phone 7. Just today it started crashing every single time it loads. If I load the game I'm currently working on it will crash. If I just open VS by itself it crashes as well. It just started today. I have no idea what suddenly caused it to start. I updated my graphics drivers but that shouldn't have caused it. I haven't done much else since I was just working on my game a couple days ago. I tried reapplying VS2010 SP1 but it failed. I tried to install windows updates for VS2010 but they apparently failed to install as well.

I'm not sure what to try now. I could try to install the updates again. I'm not sure why they keep failing to install. It just says the program has stopped working and needs to close. I've restarted a couple times as well. Any thoughts on what I could try next?

> Problem signature: 
>    Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3 
>    Problem Signature 01:    devenv.exe 
>    Problem Signature 02:    10.0.40219.1 
>    Problem Signature 03:    4d5f2a73 
>    Problem Signature 04:    mscorlib 
>    Problem Signature 05:    4.0.0.0 
>    Problem Signature 06:    4dd23522 
>    Problem Signature 07:    3789 
>    Problem Signature 08:    3e 
>    Problem Signature 09:    System.UnauthorizedAccess 
>    OS Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
>    Locale ID:   1033

Comment: Can't see why, but given you ae getting unauthorised access, have you tried running VS as administrator?

Comment: You know, I feel stupid now. Running it as admin did actually work. I never had to run it as admin before not that it's any big deal to run it as admin. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Well you could do with finding out why. Running as admin while debugging, can leave you witha deliverable you can only run as elevated by accident, particulary irritating if say UAC gets involved. Only time I've had to it, is interop with com, or debugging code with deliberate elevation.